# MySQL NOT LIKE is not not working

Tags: php, mysql

For example, I use this:

```
WHERE titel LIKE '%armband%' OR titel LIKE '%armreif%' AND titel NOT LIKE '%herren%'
```

But still get results which include words like 'Herrenarmband' and so on. Whats wrong here?

Comment: what you are trying to get with this?

Comment: "Not not working"? So it's working?

Comment: Are you serious? Take your down vote back!

Comment: one not too much ofcourse didn't sleep for over a day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
WHERE (titel LIKE '%armband%' OR titel LIKE '%armreif%') AND (titel NOT LIKE '%herren%')
```

Comment: Works :D Thanks! Will mark as accepted as soon as possible